# Replicate JS's nextUntil in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm converting a PHP and javascript application to Angular 6, and the one piece that's giving me trouble is this bit of javascript:

```
$('.toggleChild').on('click', function () {         
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('.collapsible-parent').toggleClass('open');
});
```

That `toggleChild` class was put on a `span` element, so I can replace it with a `(click)` handler, but I'm not sure how to then replicate the functionality that the JS does with TypeScript.  My click handler will get the `span` element, but then walking the tree...not sure how to handle that.

Comment: What does not work ? With the jqeury typings installed, your code works fine as is. Typescript is Javascript with types, your code should stay the same, you might need to add some type annotations or type assertions sometimes, but in this case it just works as is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Can you give more context?

Comment: It basically walks all sibling elements until it finds one with the collapsible attribute and toggles the class along the way. Basically it’s hiding or showing rows in a table.

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate the dow you should just have an array representing all the rows and have some attribute on each row that you can toggle for example

Comment: @maxime1992 Thanks.  Adding the attribute worked great.